# Aranodb Queue mechanism doesn't work with multiple database

Tags: arangodb

I am developing a foxx application which relies on job/queue mechanism of arangodb. This application runs on multiple databases. I deploy the application under _system and push the job to the queue and it runs flawlessly. But, when I add an another database and push the job (either to _system or new database) the job is added to the queue (I can see them in pending state) but are never executed.

Here is the sequnce:

1) Deploy the application under _system.
2) Push a job to the queue
3) job executes successfully

4) Add a new database, restart the arangodb and deploy the application there
5) Push a job to the queue to either _system or newly created database
6) Job gets added to the queue but never executes.

7) Delete the newly created database
8) Push the job to the queue of _system. 
9) It gets added but never executes.

Queue and Job Type names utilizes the current database name and therefore there is no name clash.

Comment: That is a bug. Can you file an issue at https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues?

Comment: The issue can be found here: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was a bug in ArangoDB. It's now fixed (see issue: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1286).